# Identify that text exceeds parbox height

Tags: boxes, warnings, height

I'm trying to identify through warnings when a text exceeds it's container parbox height with no luck.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \fboxsep0pt

    \newlength\myhg
    \newsavebox{\testparbox}
    \savebox{\testparbox}{\colorbox{red}{\parbox[b][50pt][t]{0.50\textwidth}{\blindtext}}}
    \settoheight\myhg{\usebox{\testparbox}}
    \usebox{\testparbox}
    \the\myhg
\end{document}
```

This generates the following pdf.

[image: Output pdf]

Even though the text exceeds the parbox by a considerable amount of space there are no warnings in the log outputs.

How can I identify this and throw a warning when it happens?